# Ubuntu драйвера сетевого адаптера T2U plus

Tags: ubuntu, драйвер

Установил `ubuntu` на пк, нету `wifi`, полез в интернет, понял, что нужен драйвер, установил по вот такому методу:

1) Скачал с `windows10` пакет dkms в формате .deb, установил на `ubuntu` при помощи утилиты `dgpk -i <file.deb>`

2) на `windows10` ввел комманду: `git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`, перекинул на флешку

3) на убунту зашел на флешку с `rtl8812au`, ввел комманду `sudo ./dkms-install.sh` Пишет нету данного файла(он есть). Погуглил, ввел комманду `make` подождал минут 10, ввел комманду `sudo make install`, все прошло успешно!

Перезагрузил пк... Ии... НИЧЕГО!

Помогите пожалуйста, где скачать эти драйвера и как установить??? Если что у меня есть ubuntu на ноутбуке(с интернетом).

upd: Пробовал https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues способ не работает

Comment: Я делал так - https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues

Comment: не работает :(((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Не работает это конечно понятно, но если вы укажете что же происходит, то будет более понятно

Comment: у меня писало, что все успешно, но после перезагрузки пк не видит адаптера